# d3.js (v4) + force layout + zoom проблема с tooltips

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, d3.js, zoom

На построенном графике имеются самописные `tooltips`, которые работают достаточно плавно без каких либо трансформаций:

[Пример работы без трансформаций](https://streamable.com/qfc7k)

Когда дело доходит до трансформаций, то не понятно, как выщитывать положение для `tooltips`, поэтому происходит следующее:

[Пример работы с трансформацией](https://streamable.com/z1ofy)

Сама функция для высчитывания позиции выглядит так:

```
function setPosition(element) {
    let tooltip = document.getElementById('relation-chart__tooltip');
    let zoomTransform = document
        .getElementById('zoom-wrapper')
        .getAttribute('transform');
    let translate = [];
    let transform = [];
    let scale = 0;
    if (zoomTransform) {
        translate = zoomTransform.split(' ');
        scale = translate[1].match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g)[0];
        transform = translate[0].match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
    } else {
        scale = 1;
        transform = [0, 0]
    }

    let coords = {
        x: element.getAttribute('cx') - (tooltip.offsetWidth / 2) + (parseFloat(transform[0]) / 6),
        y: element.getAttribute('cy') - tooltip.offsetHeight - 20 + (parseFloat(transform[1]) / 6)
    };
    tooltip.style.transform = `translate(${coords.x}px, ${coords.y}px) scale(${scale})`;
}
```

где через `zoomTransform` проверяется, применена ли трансформация.
Сами формулы находятся соотвественно в `coords` объекте.

Я выложил проект на хостинг: [График](http://davidarutiunian.esy.es/chart/)
Бандлер использовал Webpack, в консоли по наведению на кружок выведется объект с ссылкой на саму функцию:

[image: Объект]

где `coordX, coordY` это координаты `coords.x, coords.y`, `scale` и `transform` это трансформации соответственно.

Трансформируется элемент `g.zoom-wrapper`:

[image: Трансформация]

Собственно, вопрос в том, как высчитать положение для `tooltips`

P.S. Попытался объяснить всё максимально доступно и понятно. Надеюсь получилось :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день! 
Я пару лет назад занимался разработкой на d3.js и использовал force layout. Я привязывал прямоугольный div к каждому элементу, и эта подсказка отображается корректно при трансформациях. Однако, при движении она пропадала.

Пример: http://kirillbq.bget.ru/main
Внизу страницы - схема на d3.js с объектами и связями. Вы можете посмотреть, и если Вас заинтересует такое решение, я смогу более подробно объяснить.

Координаты рассчитывались таким образом:

function set_highlight(d)
    {

```
    svg.style("cursor","pointer");

    if ((tooltipShow)&&(d.description!="")) {

        var event = window.event;
        var x = event.pageX;
        var y = event.pageY;

        tooltip.css("display","inline");

        tooltip.offset({top:y+10, left:x+10});
        tooltip.html(d.description);

    }
}
```

, где tooltip = $("#tooltipDiv"); tooltipShow - глобальная переменная, определяющая отображать подсказку или нет.

На HTML-странице где-то создан div c id = "tooltipDiv".

Функция с данным кодом вызывалась при наведении курсора на объект

.on('mouseover', function(d){
            set_highlight(d);
        })

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Я попробую ваш приём, если сработает начислю премию :)

Comment: Ваш приём сработал хорошо, правда пришлось отказаться от трансформации размера самого тултипа. Но всё равно, спасибо!

Comment: Рад, что помогло! 
Спасибо за премию.:) Может быть это и хорошо, что тултип всегда стандартного размера. Иначе при уменьшении он тоже становится маленьким, и текст уже не виден.